# Print a string in python like how dot-matrix printer works

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns, dot-matrix

I wanted to print any English alphabet(s) using '*' or any other given special character like how a dot-matrix printer works.

I could come up with a function `def printLetters(string, font_size, special_char):` which when passed with any letter would print that letter using the special character specified.

Consider the letter 'A':

```
def printLetters('A', 10, '&'):   # would print the letter A within a 10x10 matrix using '&'

 &&&&&&&&
&        &
&        &
&        &
&&&&&&&&&&
&        &
&        &
&        &
&        &
&        &
```

and such code snippets for every character.
Example for 'A':

```
FUNCTION_TO_PRINT_A:
    space = ' '
    #print first line
    print('', special_char*(font_size-2))
    for i in range(1, font_size-1):
        #print(i)
        if font_size//2 == i:
            print(special_char*(font_size))
        print(special_char, space*(font_size-2), special_char, sep = '')

printLetters('A', 10, "&")
```

But when the parameter `string` has more than one characters, it prints gibberish after first character. 
So I just wanted some ideas/code-snippets which would print the first row of all characters in `string` first and so on until the last row so that all those *characters* line up side by side horizontally on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, fond memories.  We used to do this sort of thing all the time in the olden days before GUIs.  It is good that you want to define the shape of each letter separately, but making a separate function to print each letter is obviously not useful.  After you print the N lines of one letter, you have no way to get back to the top.

You know that you need to print the top line of ALL letters, then the 2nd line of ALL letters, etc.  I don't want to write you a complete example, because it's pretty important for you to learn how to figure this kind of thing out, but why don't you start with something like this:

```
font = {
    'A': [
        ' ###  ',
        '#   # ',
        '##### ',
        '#   # ',
        '#   # '
    ],
    'B': [
        '####  ',
        '#   # ',
        '####  ',
        '#   # ',
        '####  '
    ],
    ...etc...
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for the reply. But declaring the letters like you have, in the ```font``` variable, I would not be able to print letters at custom font sizes.
I didn't wanted any specific code either. I just wanted any ideas on how I can print letters in any given custom string in custom font sizes and special characters. 
So I have to go for writing such functions for every letters and call that to print a character of a string.
But was not sure how to print them row by row.

Comment: Ah, you want to print custom sizes...   I would actually define the font the same way even in that case, but the printing part would be somewhat more difficult.  There is no problem with special characters -- just because the font say '#' that doesn't mean you have to print the same char.

Comment: Well so, how would you print a letter in custom font size (what about ```font_size = 5``` and ```font_size = 15``` ) .How can I be using your method and at the same time, be it feasible for printing one row at a time. Thanks in adv.

Comment: It's already size=5.  To print size 15, for example, triple each row and column, and then add some logic to smooth out the chunky angles.   For sizes that aren't multiples of 5, make smart decisions about which rows and columns are 1 bigger than the others -- there are 5 cases.